# How to auto refresh DataGridView when data change in its data source

Tags: c#

As the question title say.

Who can kindly tell me the solution?

My mind is:

1. Since the DB change SQL statements (e.g. insert, update) is submit by a web service (.NET 2.0). Is it possible to send a message to a Windows Form client which owns the `DataGridView` meanwhile?
2. Is there a class achieved observer patten and it can be used to observe the table data changing?

My environment is .NET 2.0 and C#.

Could someone give me some hints?

Answer (score 0):

If your access to the database is through a webservice, the normal behaviour is that you request for updates periodically.

But not the service sending messages to the clients, because the service won't know who are the clients that are requesting.

The observer class... I don't know but making a request to update the DataGrid periodically will solve the problem, not?

Comment: Yes.I know. But it's not a grace way. Also, I wanna is one kind of triggering, a message sending way, not rotate. Thank you as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your client has access to the DB and your platforms support it, you may want to have a look at [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class.

If that web service of yours would be instead a WCF service (.NET 3.0+), it could knock on your client's doors and tell him the news with duplex operations.

Comment: Really? What a pity I'm not in the WCF's world! Thanks.

Comment: SqlDependency is available for .NET 2.0 as well. Check Version Information down that link.

Comment: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM LABEL", new SqlConnection(sqlConnStr));
            dep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
            dep.OnChange += delegate(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs args) { MessageBox.Show("SOMETHING OCCUED"); };` does not work. Any advice?

Comment: Did you enable the broker agent on your DB? "alter database DB set enable_broker"

Comment: How to enable agent? Should I config DB directly or via connection string and set `ANSI_NULLS ON ANSI_PADDING ON ANSI_WARNINGS ON
CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ONQUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON ...`OPTIONS(COPY FROM MSDN)?

Comment: Well, I'd say connection string's purpose is connection, not sending (non)queries. You can do it either "directly" or by sending an SqlCommand from your code, given that you connect to the DB with enough permissions for this op.

Comment: @Vladimir let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1726/discussion-between-user622851-and-vladimir)

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I'm working in MSSQL2005 that I know it support Sqldependency. I also issued the "ALTER...enable_broker". But no matter how code I've written following. I found when I excute SqlDependency.Start(conStr), it return false. I think that means it's impossible to implement the function I want. Could you kindly tell me why and how to config DB or some other limitations I must adopt?

Comment: @user622851 Does your user set by your connection string (conStr) have enough rights? I will give you the fishing tools rather than the fish: have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlDependencyPermissions.aspx) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SqlDependency.aspx)